# Why is there an extra part when parseUri() a String?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Uri stored as an String. I named it *launchIntent*:

```
 Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.facebook.katana cmp=com.facebook.katana/.LoginActivity }<br/>
```

When I use this
`Intent i = Intent.parseUri(launchIntent, 0);
Log.d("ABC", i.toString());` 
The Logcat gives this as the value of *i.toString()*:

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.facebook.katana cmp=com.facebook.katana/.LoginActivity } flg=0x10000000 }<br/>
```

Why there's the extra `{ act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=...` part ?

Comment: Because that's what you have set it to. The original string is not an URI btw.

Comment: The String is an Intent for launching Facebook but I have to parse it to String to store in a database. In another word if that String were an Intent I can start Facebook from it. How can I turn that into an Intent without adding or omitting anything? It's already the Intent I needed but the only problem is that it's in String.

Comment: @henry no, it's not. The extra view part stems from the fact that it is the default action used when the format of the parsed URI does not match the one given by `Intent#toUri()`, that is, when the parser is like "errr I dunno what you're trying to parse.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#parseUri(java.lang.String,%20int)) say that if the URI you are trying to parse was not generated by `myIntent.toUri()` then it will treat the String as URI and set the action to VIEW:

> Create an intent from a URI. This URI may encode the action, category, and other intent fields, if it was returned by toUri(int). If the Intent was not generate by toUri(), its data will be the entire URI and its action will be ACTION_VIEW.